# Структура Java project, inheritance

Tags: java

Можно ли придерживаться такой структуры проектов в дальнейшем, отвечает ли оно требованиям наследования. Пример, обычная считка файл. Прошу поправить, если что не так.

Главный класс

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        new ReadFile("C:\\test.txt");

    }
}
```

Второй класс того же пакета

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFile {
    private final String PATH;

    ReadFile(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        this.PATH = path;
        read(path);
    }

    void read(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        System.out.println(br.readLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: >отвечает ли оно требованиям наследования

а причём тут вообще наследование? И где оно у вас, кстати?

Comment: ок, хорошая ли здесь применена манера написания кода?

Comment: код выглядит довольно бессмысленным. Но вообще по 10 строкам кода вряд ли можно говорить о структуре проектов

Comment: Но что, по вашему здесь следует изменить?

Comment: Ваш вопрос очень расплывчат. Вы выложили кусок кода, который практически ничего не делает, и спрашиваете о некой структуре проекта и неких требованиях наследования. Так вот - о какой структуре здесь можно говорить, если тут по сути вообще ничего нет?

Comment: Хочу анализа этого 10 строчного кода и максимум критики. Спасибо

Comment: @romashechka я вам уже в третий раз говорю - здесь анализировать просто нечего, потому что тут ничего нет

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Критику говоришь?

1. Реальные пацаны не используют имя пакета типа `test`, `mytest` и вообще односложные имена пакетов. Взрослые люди регят себе домен например `romashechka.ru` и заводят имена своих пакетов типа: `ru.romashechka.test` (домен регистрировать необязательно, но мы же говорим по взрослому?)
2. Название класса всегда начинается с заглавной, то есть не `test`, а `Test`
3. Название просто final переменных не должно быть заглавными буквами, то есть не `final String PATH`, а `final String path`. Заглавными принято писать только `final static` переменные
4. Чтение файла (или вообще выбрасывание исключения) в конструкторе это плохой тон.
5. Зачем передавать методу `read()` параметр `path`? Он же уже есть в приватных членах класса
6. Выкидывать из `main()` исключение это неправильно. Кому/куда выкидываете? Кто его там будет обрабатывать? Ось? Нехорошо...
7. Хорошо бы получать имя файла из параметров `main()`
8. Неплохо бы завести собственное исключение типа: `ReadFileException`, которые внутри содержит `IOException` и `FileNotFoundException`
9. Ну и наконец тесты принято оформлять с использованием [JUnit](http://junit.org/)
10. Наследования обозначенного в вопросе нет, ну да ладно - не буду придираться.

Думаю достаточно :)

Код на троечку.

Comment: Это то, чего я ждал, спасибо ! ))

Comment: Но попрошу еще разъяснить 6, 7 пунткы

Comment: п. 6. У вас метод `main()` выкидывает исключение. Обычно исключение выкидывается, чтобы кто-то его обработал (скажем, метод вызвавший его). В случае с `main()` - это не канает, так как `main()` вызывается фактически операционной системой. В итоге юзер получит на консоль невразумительный стектрейс или еше чего похуже. В общем не юзер-френдли...

п.7. `main()` имеет параметры. [Читать здесь](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)

Comment: ну и еще раз спасибо)

Answer (score 4):

Писал утром длинный пост сюда, да гуглхром его потерял по пути, а я от огорчения пошел на работу.  Но раз [@Barmaley](/users/5648/barmaley) описал основные моменты, то присоединюсь и дополню:

1. Важно понимать, что стандарт именования пакетов - это не просто прихоти реальных пацанов, а способ поддержки уникальности пространств имен.
2. В конструкторе вообще стоит избегать внутренних вызовов и обходиться инициализацией, дабы избежать проблем в том числе и при наследовании.
3. Отдельный класс, только ради метода `main()`, который состоит из одной строки - возможно перебор. Можно положить `main()` в класс `ReadFile` и избавиться от `test`.
4. Кстати о `ReadFile`. Поскольку классы моделируют объекты, а не действия, то в качестве имен классов принято брать существительные, а не глаголы. Глаголы приберегите для имен методов.
5. Если же делаете класс, содержащий только статические методы, то стоит скрыть его конструктор и запретить наследоваться:

> ```
> public final class Test {
>     private Test() {}
>     ...
> }
> ```

.

> Неплохо бы завести собственное исключение

Соглашусь, но с оговоркой: если метод является частью интерфейса более высокого уровня, отдаваемого наружу. На каждый чих писать свое исключение несколько избыточно, когда Java снабдила нас вполне сносным набором.

Comment: @Nofate ты не поверишь, утром у меня тоже пост потерялся. Такое ощущение что по утрам сервер ложится на бок

Comment: Благодарность!